# Passing strings having special characters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, web

I am trying to pass strings with spaces and special characters, but its getting error and nothing is working.
e.g.

```
 <img onclick='addKeyword("celebritynews&gossip");' src="images/plus.png" >
```

but the '&' inside string celebritynews&gossip is breaking the code.

I figured out that the problem is in `addKeyword` function, I'd used the following code for defining a variable named url,

```
function addKeyword(categoryId){
var url = "addKeyword.php?uid=" + user_id + "&categoryId=" + categoryId + "&keyword=" + $("#keyword_" + categoryId).attr("value");
}
```

and that $("#keyword_" + categoryId) is causing problem. Any way to solve that?

Comment: Please provide some actual code, and the actual error (if you can).

Comment: Your string needs to be escaped. How you do that depends on the context that the string appears in. You will have to provide some more info about how you are passing this string around, and what exactly is misinterpreting it.

Comment: syntax error unrecognized expression:celebritynews&gossip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are passing the string on a URL, the parameter values need to be URL encoded.

...SUMMARY EDIT...

The `&` is interpreted as HTML and must be HTML encoded, specifically `&amp;`

HTML

```
<img onclick='addKeyword("celebritynews&amp;gossip");' src="images/plus.png" />
```

JavaScript

Use encodeURIComponent(s).

```
var url = "addKeyword.php?uid=" + encodeURIComponent(user_id) + "&categoryId=" + encodeURIComponent(categoryId) + "&keyword=" + encodeURIComponent($("#keyword_" + categoryId).attr("value"));
```

Comment: No i'm not passing the string, I just want to alert it ie use it in a function.

Comment: The problem is probably inside the `addKeyword()` function, then.

Comment: OK. Thanks for adding more to the question. The `&` is interpreted as HTML and must be HTML encoded, specifically `&amp;`
`<img onclick='addKeyword("celebritynews&amp;gossip");' src="images/plus.png" />`

Comment: Yes @Blazemonger I think you are correct, I'm using the following code....function addKeyword(categoryId){
    //alert(categoryId);
    var user_id='<?php echo $userId;?>';
    var url = "addKeyword.php?uid=" + user_id + "&categoryId=" + categoryId + "&keyword=" + $("#keyword_" + categoryId).attr("value");}

Comment: When i uncomment that alert(categoryId); and put a return; in front of it, that's working nice. But i want to use that url variable.

Comment: Can you detect the possible error in defination of url variable?

Comment: You need both HTML encoding and URL encoding.

`var url = "addKeyword.php?uid=" + encodeURIComponent(user_id) + "&categoryId=" + encodeURIComponent(categoryId) + "&keyword=" + encodeURIComponent($("#keyword_" + categoryId).attr("value"));`

Comment: but that $("#keyword_" + categoryId) is making errors because of categoryId having special characters, means $("#keyword_" + categoryId) could not select any element....but i'd defined a input type="text" element with id="keyword_celebritynews&gossip"

Comment: OK. The jQuery "#keyword_" + categoryId would imply that the id is id="keyword_celebritynews&gossip". Best practice is to remove/replace special characters (e.g., quotes, &, etc) so the ID is valid. You could try document.getElementById("keyword_" + categoryId) instead of jQuery in case jQuery is choking on the '&'.

Comment: @DougDomeny That's also not working, is there any way to remove all of the special characters e.g. '&' (ie functions in php and javascript that works the same and returns strings with these special characters removed)

Comment: (instead of using regular expressions)

Comment: JS: `categoryId.replace(/\W/g, "_")`


PHP: `preg_replace('/\W/g', '_', $categoryId)` [ I'm not a PHP dev ]


This uses reg exp, but they are the easiest solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<img onclick="addKeyword('<?php echo htmlspecialchars('celebritynews&gossip'); ?>')" src="images/plus.png" >
```

Comment: Please read the question again, i'd modified it a little. $("#keyword_" + categoryId) inside addKeyword() function is making problems.

Comment: $("#keyword_" + categoryId.replace(/&/g, "&amp;"))

Comment: oh i thought u wanted in js as the function was, and not in PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are writing this text to the page, you can use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to ensure it is properly escaped in the HTML.

For example:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars("celebritynews&gossip"); ?>
```

Does that help?

Comment: No it didn't helped, the output using your described function is "celebritynews&gossip" and this '&' is breaking the code, I'm thinking that javascript is assuming this to be a bitwise and.