# Cannot _GET parameters after '#' in PHP

Tags: php, get

I can't get the parameter values, if a value in the URL has the character '#'

Say if i want to set the above values to my URL parameters and print them on PHP
client=hello#56 
code=123

I'd set the URL like this, 
**www.blah.com/index.php?client=hello#56&code=123**

```
$client= isset($_GET['client']) ? $_GET['client'] : "" ;
$code= isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : "" ;


echo "This is client : $client <br /> ";
echo "This is code : $code <br />";
```

The Output will be, '

> This is client : HELLO

ONLY,
the rest of the parameters dont get displayed. 
 After doing some testing i noticed that everything after the '#' in the client parameter wont get displayed . 
 Why is this and how can i overcome this?

Comment: Part after `#` is call a fragment and never passed to server by default. You need some javascript to parse it and send to server. Or `urlencode` parameter before adding it to url.

Comment: may be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427431/passing-strings-having-special-characters

Comment: A `#` usually refers to a html elment with an `id` equal to the value that is behind the `#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from whereever the request to this file is made, `urlencode` the string before sending it. Sending data without encoding may lead to a lot of problems. For instance,any question mark (`?`) and equals (`=`) combination will trigger a new `GET` variable and the data of actual variable get's lost.

For more on encoding/decoding, see 
[PHP URL Encoding / Decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662249/php-url-encoding-decoding)

Comment: After refereeing to the decode/encode section i was able to figure it out. Thanks!